# Text in UITextField will not center properly

Tags: ios, uitextfield, alignment, placeholder

I think that my question is related to [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917949/ios-uitextfield-changes-position-when-text-is-changed).
I have a login screen with two UITextFields (user/pass). Both are horizontally center aligned with placeholder text. When I press a field, the placeholder text jumps a bit to the left and the marker is positioned after the first character (which looks awful).

[image: Text field in focus].

When I start typing, the clear button appears (as it should) but the text is not correctly centered in the UITextField view.

[image: Textfield with text]

The problem only occurs when a text field has first responder.

How can I make the darn text and placeholder text stay in the center of the text field???

UPDATE: Text field settings in Storyboard:

[image: Text field settings in Storyboard]

Comment: remove clear button=) Or add the view with the same size into `leftView`, and the same mode of displaying

Comment: NOOOOO :) Granted, that solves the problem but that can't be the only option. I would really like to have the clear button pop up when editing

Comment: post your code for reference

Comment: There is no code altering the text field. It's all done in Storyboard. See added screenshot of settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I did is that I've created my custom control that has UITextField above and UILabel below both controls has the same width and height. When I need to display text placeholder I set label alpha to 1 and when I need to hide placeholder I set alpha to 0. Also I set text inoput bg color to clear color. In addition to do all of this I implement UITextFieldDelegate (textFieldDidBeginEditing/ textFieldDidEndEditing/ shouldChangeCharactersInRange)

Answer (score -1):

Please see the control alignment in the below image and set accordingly.
It will solve your problem[image]